# How to remove documents from Collection in Meteor.js by selector?

Tags: meteor

Have you ever seen the error like me when I was trying to remove document by selector with this code in console of Google Chrome:

```
Products.remove({name:"ABC"});
```

The error is:

```
   Uncaught
    Meteor.makeErrorType.errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID.", details: undefined, 
message: "Not permitted. Untrusted code may only remove documents by ID. [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"…}
```

so what should I do to remove document by selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do like this, but

```
  Products.remove({_id: Products.findOne({name:"ABC"})._id});
```

Better use methods...

Comment: thanks for you help. I also tried the method, I think it's better.

Answer (score 1):

"The behavior of remove differs depending on whether it is called by trusted or untrusted code. Trusted code includes server code and method code. Untrusted code includes client-side code such as event handlers and a browser's JavaScript console."

From Meteor Docs: [Collection.remove()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/remove)

Client side is untrusted, so remove only works on ID. Server side Methods will allow you to remove based on a selector. So you need a method which you then call from the client side.

You should also be familiar with using: [Methods](https://www.meteor.com/try/10)

Comment: thanks for you help. It is working well with method.