# How can you delete all values that match a query in a Meteor collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have been building my Meteor React application but ran into a problem now. I would like to delete all the "fake" generated data I added. But it's not working.

I have tried several things, from server side deleting (via the console) and via a method. But none of these have worked so far.

So my question: How can you delete all data in a collection that matches a query like this one:

comments.remove({ adminSpark : { $regex: 'false', $options: 'i' }});
--> Not sure if this method is correct.

I am using SimpleSchema + ValidatedMethod.

The complete method looks like this at the moment:

```js
export const emptyDatabase = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'AllComments.remove',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    event: { type: Boolean }
  }).validator(),
  run({ event }) {
  comments.remove({ adminSpark : { $regex: 'false', $options: 'i' }});
  },
});
```

So what I want to do is delete all the comments in the collection that match adminSpark: false.

Comment: `'false'` and `false` are not the same. The first is a string and the latter is a boolean. If your `false` is a boolean, then `comments.remove({ adminSpark : false });` should work.

Comment: Use the _id strategy searching by the criteria: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29007010/1269558

Answer (score 1):

The validity of your selector depends on wether your code is trusted or not. Untrusted code can only remove elements using their _id as a selector. If you are not sure wether your code is trusted or not, I'd suggest :

```
Collection.find({/*query here*/}).map(function(doc){
   Collection.remove(doc._id);
})
```

Also this should be performed in a space were you are both subscribed to the elements you want to remove and where you have permissions to do so.
[Documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-remove):

> Trusted code can use an arbitrary Mongo selector to find the documents to remove, and can remove more than one document at once by passing a selector that matches multiple documents. It bypasses any access control rules set up by allow and deny. The number of removed documents will be returned from remove if you don’t pass a callback.
>
> As a safety measure, if selector is omitted (or is undefined), no documents will be removed. Set selector to {} if you really want to remove all documents from your collection.
>
> Untrusted code can only remove a single document at a time, specified by its _id. The document is removed only after checking any applicable allow and deny rules. The number of removed documents will be returned to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

On the server you should be able to simply do:

```
comments.remove({ adminSpark : 'false' });
```

If all your `false` values are lower case - this is an exact match.

Pray tell, why would one store false as a string instead of a boolean?

Comment: I didn't, that was my mistake.

Comment: In that case just `comments.remove({ adminSpark : false });` correct?